# how To parse this kind of json

Tags: php, json

I was just playing around google plus service and I saw the response from google server.And It looked something like below

```
)]}'

[[["er",,,,,405,,,,9]
,["di",22,,,,,[]
,[]
,,,[]
,[]
,[]
]
,["e",3,,,81]
]]
```

I removed the `)]}'` from response and tried to do json decode.

```
$arr = json_decode($response,true)
var_dump($arr);
```

But I geting error on place like multiple commas..Can some one enlighten me how google parse its json.Or is it even json or something else.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON, are you able to change the way it's generated? And actually how it's generated?

Comment: @unixarmy : Its unofficial , https://plus.google.com/_/explore?soc-app=1&cid=0&soc-platform=1&ozv=es_oz_20150623.06_p1&f.sid=-6663745606917757494&_reqid=4133&rt=j .. But I am just wondering how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is probably directly injected in some sort of "new Function" or a script tag.
The first part seems to end a prior statement.

Anyway, I'm not sure what exactly it's used for and perhaps there are some replaces done before actually working with that data.

But to solve your issue:
You need to replace all undefined indices with null.
Something along the lines of:

```
while(strpos($response, ",,") !== false) {
    $response = str_replace(",,", ",null,", $response);
}
$response = str_replace("[,", "[null,", $response);
$response = str_replace(",]", ",null]", $response);
$arr = json_decode($response,true);
var_dump($arr);
```